# How to pass ConfigMap value as env variable when using default helm charts in gitlab autodevops

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-autodevops

I am a newbie, just getting started with out of the box magic of auto devops by gitlab.

I have a very basic Golang Microservice that I am able to deploy - and it uses the default helm charts out of the box (creates namespace, service, deployment, docker registry management), and I provide my own Dockerfiles to build the docker image.

Question:

How do I read an existing K8 ConfigMap entry as environment variable to the microservice without providing a custom helm chart? ConfigMap is created in a different namespace by some other process

How do I override the namespace in which the Microservice should be deployed and not create a new namespace? I want multiple Microservices to be deployed into same namespace - I don't want a different namespace for each repository.

Basically I don't want to provide custom helm charts as I think if I provide custom chart then I will also need to do the complete setup of setting up docker registry on K8 cluster too - and I want to avoid that, I want to customize my application components, service type (I don't want ClusterIP), change namespace, refer to configMap as environment variable - without creating custom helm charts for my basic golang based micro service.

Answer (score 0):

See if [GitLab 15.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/11/22/gitlab-15-6-released/#mount-configmap-to-volumes-with-the-auto-deploy-chart) (November 2022) can help in your case:

> ### Mount `ConfigMap` to volumes with the Auto Deploy chart
>
> The default Auto Deploy Helm chart now supports the `extraVolumes` and `extraVolumeMounts` options.
>
> In past releases, you could specify only [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistent-volumes) for Kubernetes.
>
> Among other use cases, you can now mount:
>
> - Secrets and ConfigMaps as files to Deployments, CronJobs, and Workers.
> - Existing or external Persistent Volumes Claims to Deployments, CronJobs, and Workers.
> - Private PKI CA certificates with hostPath mounts to achieve trust with the PKI.
>
> Thanks to [Maik Boltze](https://gitlab.com/MBcom) for this community contribution.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/customize.html#custom-helm-chart) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-deploy-image/-/issues/202).